# VMWare fills the host disk and it needs reboot of the host system

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I am using VMWare to run 2 virtual machines.

However, after some time, the available space on the hard disk (~200G) has been filled by VMWare. After a reboot the space is available again.

This is a problem because, when the host machine runs out of space, the virtual machines are paused. Then, they need to be restarted after the reboot.

How can I solve this problem without needing to reboot?

The host system is Ubuntu, the guest systems are Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Exactly what files are consuming all of the available space?

Comment: I am unable to find them.. What do you propose to do to find them? In the VM folder I cannot find any large file, except for the vmdk files..

Comment: `du` or perhaps one of the things suggested at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-to-understand-whats-taking-up-space

Comment: Thanks, I found that the problem was the file `.xsession-errors`. I temporarily solved with this: http://askubuntu.com/a/94538/52284